# Password OAuth Flow (cURL + Connected App) keeps returning Authentication error

Tags: rest-api, oauth2

We are currently using the following command to generate a token, however the server keeps returning an error.

**Command:**

```
curl -v https://{instance}.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token
    -d "grant_type=password"
    -d "client_id={appKey}"
    -d "client_secret= {appSecret}"
    -d "username={loginUserName}"
    -d "password={Key}{Token}"
    -H "X-PrettyPrint: 1"
```

**Error:**

> ```
> {
>     "error" : "invalid_grant",
>     "error_description" : "authentication failure"
>     * Connection #0 to host login.salesforce.com left intact
> }
> ```

**Things we've tried (including reading documentation and Q&A both on SF Community and here):**

1. Using login.salesforce.com rather than the instance (naXX)
2. Using test.salesforce.com rather than the instance (naXX)
3. Not using a password token (with different endpoints from #1,#2)
4. Setting IP Restrictions to relaxed
5. Setting users to authenticate themselves
6. Setting network access to the IP being used to send the command (both start and end IP.)
7. Trying alternate grant_type (s) to see what happened (alternate errors for those respective auth flows.)
8. Sending the parameters as one query string

**EDIT**

I have posted the proper answer below.

Comment: Please don't just blindly blame the user base. Regardless, the information from your last edit is not part of what you are trying to ask, so I removed it in addition to cleaning up your list formatting.

Comment: Hi Adrian. I've further edited my edit in response to your edits, and responded to your comment in my answer below. Given the "recommended deletions" under the "From Review" link, the user base address was warranted. The answer remains valid (including its brevity), and at this point, it is a waste of time to continue fighting this battle. For anyone else who stumbles upon this question, I do hope the answer below helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user type (Eg: "Administrator") must have the connected app enabled in their profile.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/91685)

Comment: I am the author, so yes, it does answer the question.

Comment: Hi SFExplorer, I agree this answer is likely useful for future visitors who encounter the same issue, but answers which are this short actually get flagged automatically. Please take a moment to read [answer]. In this particular case, linking to articles which helped discover the issue would greatly improve the quality of your answer. And any time you include a link, it is highly advisable to cite the relevant content here in a blockquote (you start the line with a `>` character).

Comment: Hi Adrian, thank you for the clarification on automatic flagging. When I looked at the "From Review" link under Reshma's post, I noticed the two "Recommended deletions" from particular users. In this particular case, there is obviously an exception to the automatic flag. In regards to particular links, it was actually trial and error on my part. Thus, the brevity of the answer is warranted.

Comment: Once the system flags an answer, it enters a `Review Queue` where many users can vote on whether or not the automatic flag has merit. I still highly recommend you **[edit]** your answer to include one or two of the most helpful links you found.

Comment: Is there context with the Review Queue? If not, this seems highly inefficient and explains my historical concerns with some math proofs, etc found in other areas of the Stack Exchange network. In regards to your secondary request for links, there were no helpful links. The answer, along with the list of other trial and error scenarios, was my own work. Why would I add and respectively credit links just to suit a clearly inefficient system flag? Eg: 2+2=4. No link required.